# Having trouble with - class 'pandas.core.indexing._AtIndexer'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, data-cleaning

I'm working on a ML project to predict answer times in stack overflow based on tags. Sample data:

```
Unnamed: 0  qid i   qs  qt  tags    qvc qac aid j   as  at
0   1   563355  62701.0 0   1235000081  php,error,gd,image-processing   220 2   563372  67183.0 2   1235000501
1   2   563355  62701.0 0   1235000081  php,error,gd,image-processing   220 2   563374  66554.0 0   1235000551
2   3   563356  15842.0 10  1235000140  lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure  1047    16  563358  15842.0 3   1235000177
3   4   563356  15842.0 10  1235000140  lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure  1047    16  563413  893.0   18  1235001545
4   5   563356  15842.0 10  1235000140  lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure  1047    16  563454  11649.0 4   1235002457
```

I'm stuck at the data cleaning process. I intend to create a new column named 'time_taken' which stores the difference between the at and qt columns.
Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("answers.csv")
df['time_taken'] = 0
print(type(df.time_taken))
for i in range(0,263541):
    val = df.qt[i]
    qtval = val.item()
    val = df.at[i]
    atval = val.item()
    df.time_taken[i] = qtval - atval
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-39-9384be9e5531>", line 1, in <module>
    val = df.at[0]

  File "D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2080, in __getitem__
    return super().__getitem__(key)

  File "D:\Softwares\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2027, in __getitem__
    return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)

TypeError: _get_value() missing 1 required positional argument: 'col'
```

The problem here lies in the indexing of  **df.at**
Types of both df.qt and df.at are

```
<class 'pandas.core.indexing._AtIndexer'> 
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> respectively.
```

I'm an absolute beginner in data science and do not have enough experience with pandas and numpy.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please remove the image of your data and replace it was a sample of your data formatted with `pd.DataFrame()`.

Comment: No problem at all; [`pd.read_clipboard()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html) can read it fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, to put it mildly, an easier way to do this.

```
df['time_taken'] = df['at'] - df.qt
```

The `AtIndexer` issue comes up because [`.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) is a pandas method. You want to make sure to not name columns any names that are the same as a Python/Pandas method for this reason. You can get around it just by indexing with `df['at']` instead of `df.at`.

Besides that, this operation — if I'm understanding it — can be done with one short line vs. a long for loop.

Comment: Great catch, @k_n_c!  +1

Comment: Also, just a side note.   I highly recommend always using `df['colname']` notation over using `df.colname` dot notation.  The dot notation has its limits, and you found one here.  `df['time_taken'] = df['at'] - df['qt']`

Comment: You're right bracket notation is safer/better in that it always works. I prefer using dot notation when possible because I find it easier to read and limits the numer of brackets in code (and is also faster to type). For me, I also got more knowledgable about the limits of dot notation *by using it* in cases where it broke.